# Prove that the equation $Q(P(x)) = 1$ has no integer solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let the polynomials $P(x) , Q(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]  $and integer $ a$ satisfy:

$P(a)= P(a+2015) = 0 $

$Q(2014)=2016$

Prove that the equation $Q(P(x)) = 1$ has no integer solution .

Assume that equation $Q(P(x)) = 1$ has an integer  solution $\Rightarrow $ Equation $Q(x) = 1$ has  at least one integer solution.

$\Rightarrow $ $Q(x)-1 = (x-m)R(x)$

$\Rightarrow $ $Q(2014)-1 = (2014-m)R(x)$

$\Rightarrow $ $2015 = (2014-m)R(x)$

$\Rightarrow $ $(2014-m)$ $\in$ {${\pm 1 ; \pm 2015 ; \pm 5 ; \pm 403 }$ }

$\Rightarrow $ $m$ $\in$ {${ 2013;2015;-1;4029;2009;2019;1611;2417  }$ }

$P(a)= P(a+2015) = 0 $ $\Rightarrow $ $a$ and $(a+2015)$ are solutions of the polynomial $P(x)$

$\Rightarrow $ $P(x) = (x-a)(x-a-2015)g(x) $

But at this point, I have no more ideas. I'm so sorry everyone for my stupidity. I hope to get help from everyone. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints.** Prove the following:

1. Note that $a$ and $a + 2015$ have different parity. But $P$ takes the value $0$ on both of them. Thus, $P$ always takes even values at *every* integer.
2. You have $Q(2014) = 2016$. Thus, $Q$ take even values at *even* integers.
3. Conclude that $Q \circ P$ cannot take an odd value at *any* integer. In particular, $Q(P(x)) = 1$ has no integer solution.

---

The idea in 1. and 2. is the same: If $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ is a polynomial, then for all integers $a, b \in \Bbb Z$, we have $$a \equiv b \pmod 2 \implies f(a) \equiv f(b) \pmod 2.$$